# probability on strategy expected return

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading, high-frequency

I’ve been thinking about this for awhile and couldn’t figure it out myself.

Assume you have a trading strategy, which return is normally distributed.
strategy return has a mean of 1 basis point and a standard deviation of 20 basis points.
Now, how many times do you have to run this strategy so there’s a 99% chance you don’t lose money (your expected return is 0) ?

I understand that if returns are normally distributed , then from Z score I can calculate the probability of any return. However that doesn’t solve the above problem...

Comment: Are returns multiplicative or additive? Zero times is one answer ;)

Comment: Set up the problem in Excel and try it out yourself! You can use Monte Carlo simulation to answer your question. Generate a bunch time series of random draws using RAND() and NORM.DIST. Then in the final column, use COUNTIF() to see how many of your time series are above 0 at every time step. If you do 10000 time series, look for where your COUNTIF shows 9900.

Comment: @BobJansen that’s true!

Comment: It does make a difference whether returns are multiplicative or additive though.

Comment: By [Cantelli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality), if you run it 40,000 times (!) for additive returns, the mean is 40K bps, and the standard deviation is 4K bps, so the probability of a loss is smaller than $1/101$. This is covered in chapter 2 of [Short Sharpe Course](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3036276).